# How does background:currentColor add a line?

Tags: css

In the following example (from Mozilla's site):

`<div style="color:darkred">  The color of this text is the same as the one of the line:   <div style="background:currentcolor; height:1px"></div>  Some more text. </div>`

[Please take a look at this corresponding jsfiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/Gay5C/)

If I remove "background:currentColor" from the style, the line it draws disappears.  How does a style like this result in the addition of a line?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could tell us why you have the empty div, with a height of 1px, in there. The line doesn't disappear, it's colour is just changed to white. (Colour of the body)

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

Comment: @anothershrubery: As I said, I took the example as is from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/color_value#currentColor_Keyword

Comment: Ah right, so you were just looking an explanation as to why it worked that way? Then Mr Disappointment has that covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `div` has a height of one pixel (1px), which means it is *presented* as a line - namely because there is no content of *x-pixels height* within it, it sizes itself appropriately (if no `height` was specified then it would collapse to 0). Therefore, because the `div` has a background colour (which doesn't match the colour on which it is rendered (which, if the colours did match, would give the illusion of invisibility)) you see one pixel height line of that colour.

Think of crushing a box down, or folding paper: you couldn't make it entirely disappear (out of existence, or current form, at least not easily) and, upon bringing yourself horizontal to the plane on which it sat, would still see it (or its colour/shade of, etc.)

Of course, concentrating on only that one not a solution wouldn't be too helpful, although others have come to your aid: use a `span` element to 'group' text within text, these are `inline` by default and by rights should only be output if there is text to go in one - this forgets for a moment that you explicitly specify a `height` value at all, which is what makes me wonder about the whole scenario.

Comment: Thank you. (Hardly a disappointing answer!)  The only part I did not understand: "has a background colour which doesn't match the colour on which it is rendered (to give the illusion of invisibility)".  If the background and the rendered-on colors don't match, then you would have *visibility*, not invisibility?  I am sure I am missing something essential here.

Comment: @Sabuncu Yes, I tried clearing up my wording on that point. (:

Answer (score 2):

because Div is a block element.

```
<div style="color:darkred">  The color of this text is the same as the one of the line:   <span style="background:currentcolor; height:1px"></span>  Some more text. </div> ​
```